# jQuery/post(): the URL called is not what I expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a link at `http://myweb.localhost/miembros/id/1/mensajes`. When I click that link, the code below is called:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $('.switch_leido').click(function(){

     $.post('mensaje/cambiarEstadoLeido',
            {id:$(this).data('leido')},
            function(){
              alert("fasfsf");
            }
     );
   });
```

and I get this error:

> POST http://myweb.localhost/miembros/id/1/mensaje/cambiarEstadoLeido 404 (Not
>   Found)

Instead, I expected `http://myweb.localhost/mensaje/cambiarEstadoLeido` was called but no..:S

What should I do?

Javier

Comment: Try changing putting  a / in front of mensaje

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path is set relative.  Use a "/" in front to reference the root of the web site

```
 $.post('/mensaje/cambiarEstadoLeido', ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an absolute path? maybe change to

```
 $.post('/mensaje/cambiarEstadoLeido',
```